Headlight burnout
My son has a vehicle in which the headlights keep randomly burning out.  They may last a month, a day or a year.  I know only a small amount about electronics but i assume that there is too much current blowing the bulbs.   I also assume there is too much voltage causing the issue...not sure.  I havent tested the voltage yet.   Would the fuse not blow if there was too many amps going to the bulb?  I thought this would be an easy fix...just add a diode to drop the votage or maybe a xener diode but i dont think this will work because of the amount of watts the bulb requires.   Would some kind of voltage regulator help?   The car manufacturer issued a recall but the time has expired.  I read online that they installed a wire harness going to the bulbs.  The issue is with the bright and dim bulbs.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Some details would help like year/make/model, type of lamps (Incandescent? LED?) etc. Also, have you checked the alternator voltage - that's probably what's acting up.

most "bulb" modules i've seen recently have power supplies / LED drivers integrated into the package, so dropping the voltage going to it won't help. Buying better replacements is about the best thing to do here.

does your son have an after-market audio system installed into the car?

Alternator should read 14.2 V nom.  Any unusual symptoms like moisture? excess brightness ? loose fixture? What type of bulb? It matters

The car is a 2011 toyota prius.  I was told that it has had this issue since it was new.   Just occassionally burn out the bulbs.   I just learned that it is only the dim bulbs.   I will check the alternator voltage.   I think they are halogen bulbs bug i am not sure.  I saw a video where someone helped the issue by buying LED bulbs and he has done that but not installed them yet.   I wanted to make sure something else wasnt going on first.

If a recall was issued it should still be possible to purchase the repair part, even if you no longer qualify for free service.
Check that the alternator wire is intact.

Thanks for the quick responses everyone.   I was able to find the recall parts through the Toyota dealer.  Thanks again
